# Error when importing list template

Tags: 2013, 2016, list-template

When importing a list template that includes content I get the following error:

`A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe`

I'm importing a list template created in SharePoint 2016, into a SharePoint 2013 site.

Importing the template works fine, I can create the list with no issues, but when seeing the contents of the list the above error is shown.

Comment: Did you add any script editor/content editor web part on list view or list form pages?

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue, though I'm moving a 2019 template to 2013. Too bad no real answer has been stated. The guru I usually go to in such situations seems to think it is a farm side setting in 2013 which is causing the issue. Our farm admin can't seem to find time to figure anything out. Maybe this activity will bounce this up a bit and smoeone can answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Does the default view from source list has any custom webpart added?

Can you directly visit "List settings" and create new view from list setting and try to open newly created view? If that works, you can set this as default view.

list settings can be opened by **sites/sitename/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=GUIDOFDESTINATIONLIST**

Also screenshot might help further troubleshoot this.